# android Json Api Key Value Nested how to use

Tags: android, android-volley

Android Json Api Key Nested how to use ?MsgID ,UsrID Repeat how to call? Volley

I have a json which has a number of nested JSONARRAY.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "2547": {
        "MsgID": "2547",
        "UsrID": "352",
        "MsgID": "221",
        "ThroughUsrID": null,
        "MsgID": "1",
        "MsgDt": "2016-03-22 11:55:13",
        "buscard": {
            "UsrID": "221",         
            "EntID": "7",
            "EntID": "1",
            "UsrFavorites": 0,
            "UsrLinkSts": "connected"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Requesting you to kindly improve your English, audients will not be able to understand if you write like this "MsgID ,UsrID Repeat how to call? Volley"

Comment: Go through this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: can you edit your question because is very hard do undestand what you asking .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to parse Json data. Try to do something like this:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringToParse);
        JSONObject data = jsonObject.optJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject tempData = data.optJSONObject("2547");
        String msgID = tempData.optString("MsgID");

        // Similarly parse other info


        JSONObject busCard = tempData.optJSONObject("buscard");

        //Again parse required data from busCard


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```